# IDEA, How to set up remote debugging?

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-debugging

Eclipse allows to connect to a remote process via a TCP port for remote debugging.

[image]

Does IDEA allow that? How can it be configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEA can do same that!! you can do as following steps:
1. enter Step --> edit configuration 
2. Click Add (plus symbol at the left top) --> select remote
3. This screen 'll show to u:
[image]

you can alter host, port (where program live on), and run java with argument ,

4. start debug with this configuration 
   :D :D